# Process Uploaded Image Before Saving Through Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, dropbox-api

I have a form that allows me to upload the image. Then in the controller I get the uploaded image and run some processes on the image. After the image is processed I store it in the `/public/` folder.

I want to take that image and give it to paperclip to save. Can someone please advise me on how I can achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use Paperclip's built-in ability to add extra post-processing? Check out the docs here http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/3.5.1/Paperclip/Processor

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:-
I am assuming this model.

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
has_attached_file :avatar
end
```

In your controller

```
def someaction
 a = SomeModel.new
 #you did your processing here and saved it in public folder
 # if you have file object, you can use it or 
 f = File.open((File.join(Rails.root, "public", filename)))
 a.avatar = f
 a.save
end
```